# http or https authentication for Intranet Web applications

Tags: http, authentication, https

I’m developing an Intranet application and I want to make a secure authentication.

One approach can be use “https”. The problem is that the server doesn’t have a trusted certificate, therefore is a bit annoying for the client because the browser doesn’t trust in the certificate and complaints with a scary message.

Using http will compromise the user password but it can be combined with [“Digest access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication)”

What do you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**2023 Update**

Cloud vendors allow you to automatically provision SSL certificates for non-public domains (e.g. [AWS Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/)). There are also self-hosted private certificate managers such as [this one](https://github.com/smallstep/certificates).

SSL for intranet/internal cloud connections is strongly recommended and may be required for PCI and SOC 2 certification.

**2009 Answer**

Purchase a domain and trusted certificate?  They are really not that expensive anymore if you shop around.

Having said that, digest access authentication is reasonably safe for authentication.  Using http rather than https, all of the information you send across the wire will be plain text even if the password is not.  Anyone that can plug a laptop in to your intranet running an application such as WireShark can view all of the information sent back and forth.  If you care about that information not being compromised, http will not meet your needs.

Comment: "Anyone that can plug a laptop in to your intranet running an application such as WireShark can view all of the information sent back and forth"

While that is true of wireless, that is not true in a switched network (which is what you probably have with the Ethernet plug in the wall). You'll only be able to see broadcast traffic. HTTP is not broadcast.

Comment: The problem is that you can't buy certificates for internal domains. Only for global domains like .com, .net etc.

Comment: @Timmmm You can use certificates for internal domains now (I just implemented this for a PCI-compliant environment). Updated the answer with two approaches.

Answer (score 10):

These are (y)our options:

1. If you have mostly Windows hosts, you can [Distribute Certificates
   to Client Computers by Using Group Policy | Microsoft
   Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/distribute-certificates-to-client-computers-by-using-group-policy)
   and use your own self-signed certificate in this way.

   - Non windows users or Windows machines not in the domain will have to
     go through the hoops and warnings of either installing the
     certificate properly manuallly or allowing the self-signed certificate.
     A bad user experience.
2. You use a proper domain name, a real certificate and a messy DNS
   configuration where www.mycompany.com resolves to an external site,
   but wiki.mycompany.com is an internal site (But please, please don't put the internal
   address for wiki.mycompany.com in an externally visible DNS record!)
3. You don't use HTTPS at all and use HTTP. Possibly by inventing your
   own security for login pages (Yikes!)

They all suck.

Especially if you want to distribute an enterprise-ready onsite app, and you don't know the customer's network and DNS configuration beforehand.

Answer (score 8):

As of November 2015 you [can't buy certificates for internal domains](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/important-changes-ssl-certificates-intranets-what-you-need-know) so as far as I know the only option is to pre-install the certificates on clients. Not a great solution.

Another possability if you want to keep your internal domains private is to create a public domain:  mycompany.com, and then run your own DNS server internally that resolves your internal domains:   `accounting.internal.mycompany.com`, `hr.internal.mycompany.com` and so on. Then I believe you can use a wildcard certificate for `mycompany.com`. I haven't tested this solution.

Answer (score 4):

You have these options:

1. Purchase a trusted certificate.
2. Or, generate your own root certificate, install it in browsers on all intranet computers (you should be able to do it since it's intranet), generate your own server certificate signed with your own root certificate. This is actually what companies often do.

Note: Digest access authentication is not helpful if you want to have form authentication (a HTML form with user, password, login page using the visual style of your app, nicer wrong-password error reporting, possibly additional features such as "remember me" or "forgot password").

Answer (score 1):

If you need it to be a fully secure, you should purchase the SSL certificate.

From the wiki link you provided:

**Disadvantages**

Digest access authentication is intended as a security trade-off; it is intended to replace unencrypted HTTP Basic access authentication which is extremely weak. However it is not intended to replace strong authentication protocols, such as Public key or Kerberos authentication.

I think there's your answer :)

Comment: Purchasing a certificate _is not possible_ if the domain is `hostname.internal.domain`, which is the case when deploying internal "Intranet" apps to  most/all enterprise environments.